# Is there a way in SQL Server to sequence data by a group?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of data that has the following columns

```
EmployeeID-Date-Time
```

The data is going into a timeclock system. I am ultimately trying to find a way to sequence the data by employee because my output needs to look like this.

```
EmployeeID-DateIN-TimeIN-DateOut-Timeout
```

The problem is that there is no easy way to tell how many entries per employee there could be in a day. These are bus drivers so they clock in and out for their morning route, afternoon route, and possibly even fieldtrips in the middle. Plus what happens if they miss a punch and now have an uneven number of rows.

Anyway I am trying to get the following example as my input and output.

```
Input
12345-8/25/22-08:45
12345-8/25/22-09:45
12345-8/25/22-13:00
12345-8/25/22-13:30
23456-8/25/22-10:00
23456-8/25/22-11:00

Output
12345-8/25/22-08:45-8/25/22-09:45
12345-8/25/22-13:00-8/25/22-13:30
23456-8/25/22-10:00-8/25/22-11:00
```

I am very new to SQL so I don't even know if it's possible but appreciate the help!

Comment: So how do you know which row is IN and which row is OUT especially if one is "missed"? There must be more data in your table than this - what about your primary key? The best you can probably do do is group them in pairs, then your output is just a pivot. Provide more info, including the column data types - SQL Server has *datetime* types so why are you not using one of those?

Comment: Pairing them off is easy. It's the missing data that makes this difficult. If you can define some boundaries around shift windows or something then you could start identifying which ones should be flagged as missing either a clock-in or clock-out.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL. Yet another use-case of GIGO: Garbage in, Garbage out. In other words: If the front-end doesn't give a damn about the data quality, no one should expect anything from the back-end.

Comment: Agreed it is garbage in, they're trying to pigeon hole a student tracking system into a punch in and out system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id
      ,date
      ,date2
from   (      
        select id
              ,dt as "date"
              ,lead(dt)     over (partition by id order by dt) as "date2"
              ,row_number() over (partition by id order by dt) as  rn
        from t
        ) t
where rn % 2 != 0
order by id
```

| id | date | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2022-08-25 08:45:00.000 | 2022-08-25 09:45:00.000 |
| 12345 | 2022-08-25 13:00:00.000 | 2022-08-25 13:30:00.000 |
| 23456 | 2022-08-25 10:00:00.000 | 2022-08-25 11:00:00.000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ddadfd87f085ea64a9d11bc361aa0aff&hide=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
 WITH T1 AS (
 SELECT EmpId, InOut, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY InOut) AS RowNumber
 FROM Clock )

 SELECT T1.EmpId, T1.InOut AS I, T2.InOut AS O
 FROM T1 
    INNER JOIN T1 AS T2 ON T1.EmpId = T2.EmpId AND  T1.RowNumber + 1 = T2.RowNumber 
                                               AND  T2.RowNumber % 2 = 0
```